# Gatsby serve - Issue with canvas on initial render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, gatsby

I have an eraser effect with canvas on my Gatsby application. On the home page users can erase the canvas to see the video underneath the canvas.

Everything works as normal on my local machine but when I serve the app, the canvas and video do not load initially. However, if I navigate to any page within the app and back to home page, the canvas and video load and work properly.

Please how can I resolve this.

Please see below code:

```
const HomePage = () => {
  let canvas = useRef(null)
  const size = useWindowSize()
  const { currentTheme } = useGlobalStateContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    let renderingElement = canvas.current
    let drawingElement = renderingElement.cloneNode()

    let drawingCtx = drawingElement.getContext("2d")
    let renderingCtx = renderingElement.getContext("2d")

    let lastX
    let lastY

    let moving = false

    renderingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"
    renderingCtx.fillStyle = currentTheme === "dark" ? "#000000" : "#ffffff"
    renderingCtx.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    renderingElement.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
      moving = true
      lastX = e.pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft
      lastY = e.pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop
    })

    renderingElement.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      moving = false
      lastX = e.pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft
      lastY = e.pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop
    })

    renderingElement.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      if (moving) {
        drawingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"
        renderingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"
        let currentX = e.pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft
        let currentY = e.pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop
        drawingCtx.lineJoin = "round"
        drawingCtx.moveTo(lastX, lastY)
        drawingCtx.lineTo(currentX, currentY)
        drawingCtx.closePath()
        drawingCtx.lineWidth = 120
        drawingCtx.stroke()
        lastX = currentX
        lastY = currentY

        renderingCtx.drawImage(drawingElement, 0, 0)
      }
    })
  }, [currentTheme, size])

  return (
    <Container>
      <Video>
        <video
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          loop
          autoPlay
          muted
          src={require("../assets/somevideo.mp4")}
        />
      </Video>
      <Canvas
        width={size.width}
        height={size.height}
        ref={canvas}
      />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

#useWindowSize.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function useWindowSize() {
  const hasWindow = typeof window !== "undefined"

  function getSize() {
    const width = hasWindow ? window.innerWidth : null
    const height = hasWindow ? window.innerHeight : null
    return {
      width,
      height,
    }
  }

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize())

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasWindow) {
      function handleResize() {
        setWindowSize(getSize())
      }

      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)

      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize)
    }
  }, [hasWindow])

  return windowSize
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was a rehydration issue, where React and Gatsby are having trouble matching data that came from the server with the change you want to do in the client.

Since, my home page has a canvas animation that is generated on the client not server.
I can hold off my home page from rendering until I know for sure the client has fully loaded.

So I edited my index page to the following and this fixed the issue for me.

```
const Index = () => {
  const [isClient, setClient] = useState(false);
  const key = isClient ? "client" : "server";


  useEffect(() => {
    setClient(true);
  }, []);

  if ( !isClient ) return null;
  return (
    <div key={key}>
     <HomePage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook will not run when rendering server-side. I suspect `useWindowSize` is also using `useEffect`, so your canvas is probably being drawn at 0x0 px initially. When React rehydrates, your `useEffect` callback in the `HomePage` component captures the current reference for `size` (closure), which is going to be something like `{ width: 0, height: 0 }`. Since you haven't declared `size` as a dependency in your `useEffect` callback, the newly created function won't be called.

To fix, you should just need to add `size` to the `useEffect` dependency array.

You can avoid missing this in the future by using [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) with your eslint setup.

Comment: Hi, I added size as a dependency in my useEffect function, but I still do not get the desired results. I have updated my question with the useWindowSize hook file